# How to perform jwt token verification in java

Tags: java, jwt

I have jwt token with me and passed in below function.
its just i need to verify the jwt token.
algorithm='HS256'

```
void  authenticate_web_socket_connection1(String jwtToken){
    String secret="some random key";
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
       .setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(secret))
       .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken).getBody();
```

Getting below error:
**ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.**
**Exception in thread "main" io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.**

Comment: I am using this but it is giving the same error,

Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKey).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody()


can you assist on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this method to get all Claims from token.

```
private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {

   return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

}
```

Let me know if works for you.

Comment: My secret key is called from properties file @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret; , so, i dont know if DatatypeConverter is the problem. I think the problem its other. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639392/jwt-signature-does-not-match-locally-computed-signature-jwt-validity-cannot-be)

Comment: verification logic was correct but its just i was incorrectly signing the token. so my problem is solved now