Spring boot role-based access: Cannot access endpoint based
I have a user with role "ROLE_USER", i can signin this user with no problem and signin endpoint generates a JWT each time i hit it with n o problem. I'm trying to trigger an endpoint with signedin user with jwt and role-based authentication. When i try to trigger the endpoint below, i get these two errors:

d.s.s.security.jwt.JwtUtils              : Invalid JWT signature: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.


d.s.s.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt: Unauthorized error: Full
authentication is required to access this resource

Here is the related code below:
AuthController.java:
package dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.controller;

import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.model.EnumRole;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.model.Role;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.model.User;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.payload.request.LoginRequest;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.payload.request.SignupRequest;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.payload.response.JwtResponse;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.repository.RoleRepository;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.repository.UserRepository;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.services.RefreshTokenService;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.services.UserDetailsImpl;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                          UserRepository userRepository,
                          PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                          RoleRepository roleRepository,
                          JwtUtils jwtUtils,
                          RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
        this.refreshTokenService = refreshTokenService;
    }

    public AuthController() {
    }

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signin(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String token = jwtUtils.generateToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).toList();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token, userDetails.getId(), userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getEmail(), roles));
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signupRequest) {
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signupRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Username is already taken");
        }
        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signupRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Email is already taken");
        }

        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = encoder.encode(signupRequest.getPassword());
        User user = new User(signupRequest.getUsername(), signupRequest.getEmail(), encodedPassword);
        Set<Role> userRoles = signupRequest.getRoles();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (userRoles == null) {
            Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER").orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role is not found"));
            roles.add(role);
        } else {
            userRoles.forEach(role -> {
                if (role.getName().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                    Role role1 = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN").orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role is not found"));
                    roles.add(role1);
                } else if (role.getName().equals("ROLE_MODERATOR")) {
                    Role role1 = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_MODERATOR").orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role is not found"));
                    roles.add(role1);
                } else {
                    Role role1 = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER").orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role is not found"));
                    roles.add(role1);
                }
            });
        }
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
}

TestController.java
package dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.controller;

import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String all() {
        return "public content";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String user() {
        return "user content";
    }

    @GetMapping("/moderator")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String mod() {
        return "moderator content";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String admin() {
        return "admin content";
    }
}

AuthEntryPointJwt.java:
package dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.jwt;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        HashMap<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
        body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
        body.put("path", request.getServletPath());

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
    }
}

WebSecurityConfig.java:
package dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security;

import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private AuthEntryPointJwt entryPointJwt;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, AuthEntryPointJwt entryPointJwt) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.entryPointJwt = entryPointJwt;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPointJwt))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").authenticated());
        http.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}

AuthTokenFilter.java
package dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.jwt;

import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = parseJwt(request);
        try {
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.generateUsernameFromToken(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());

                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication {}", e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(header) && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return header.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

JwtUtils.java:
package dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.jwt;

import dev.spring.spring_jwt_auth.security.services.UserDetailsImpl;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtUtils {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${app.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${app.jwtExpirationTime}")
    private int jwtExpirationTime;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder()
                .subject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                .issuedAt(new Date())
                .expiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationTime))
                .signWith(Jwts.SIG.HS512.key().build(), Jwts.SIG.HS512)
                .compact();
    }

    public SecretKey key() {
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(secretKey));
    }

    public String generateUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts
                .parser()
                .verifyWith(Jwts.SIG.HS512.key().build())
                .build()
                .parseSignedClaims(token)
                .getPayload()
                .getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts
                    .parser()
                    .verifyWith(Jwts.SIG.HS512.key().build())
                    .build()
                    .parseSignedClaims(token);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}

Any help is appreciated!

maybe this might help a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639392/jwt-signature-does-not-match-locally-computed-signature-jwt-validity-cannot-be

@Stultuske I tried the solution you linked but it didnt work due to library version differences

i do not understand why you have chosen to build some kind of homemade security and not chosen to use the implemented security standards that exist in spring security. What you have built is called PASSWORD GRANT TYPE and is deemed to be not implemented https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password and thats the reason this does not exist in spring security.

and your problem is here .signWith(Jwts.SIG.HS512.key().build(), Jwts.SIG.HS512) you generate a random key to sign your JWT. Then when you are going to verify the signature a couple of rows down you generate a new random key .verifyWith(Jwts.SIG.HS512.key().build()) and when you are getting the subject from the token you AGAIN generate a random key .verifyWith(Jwts.SIG.HS512.key().build()) you need to generate a public and private key where you use the private key to sign the jwt, and then use public keys to verify the jwt.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538047/jwt-private-public-key-confusion

Hi @Toerktumlare, i built this project solely for learning purpose. I do not intend to release it for production etc. I know that i need to implement OAuth for production project. As for your second comment, I'll check it out too see what I did wrong. Thank you for your answers.

i dont really see the point with learning how to build something insecure and not recommended. None of your implementation exists in the official docs. Learn from the docs. Not random blogs.
